# How to go through each observation of a data frame?

Tags: r

I have a data frame in R with 200 observations with 400 variables.
When I do:

```
for (i in data_frame) {
   print(i)   count <- count + 1
}
```

The code goes through each variable and print 200 observations. In the end count is 400.
I want to go through each observation and print the 400 variables (in a way that in the end count = 200). How can I do that?

Comment: could you provide an example of the desired output please?

Comment: I have the data frame:
1 2 3 4 
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
And I want to print:
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
And it is print
1 1 1
2 2 2

Comment: `for (i in nrow(data_frame))`

Comment: I'd suggest `View(data_frame)` in RStudio is a better way to inspect the rows. In general, data frames are objects that we manipulate and work with, rather than inspecting the entire object visually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the limited information in the post, the solution I can suggest attempting is the following:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(data_frame)) {
   print( data_frame[i,] )   
}
```

I removed `count` since I do not see the value of keeping it in the loop.